# Importing package from a private Bitbucket repository through composer

Tags: php, git, laravel, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a package setup in a private Bitbucket repository that I use across a variety of Laravel based client projects. I find I am regularly adding to it and would like to be able to update each client's project using composer as needed with the latest edition.

How do I add an entry into composer to pull from the Bitbucket git repository without having to expose my personal repository login/password to the clients in the composer.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ssh authentication](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+SSH+protocol+with+Bitbucket) and configure some [Deployment Keys](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+deployment+keys):

- Go into "Project Settings -> Deployment Keys"
- Then add a different deployment key for each of your clients.

You can find more info on the links on how to set-up ssh authentication with Mercurial or Git.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I can't figure out how to reference the SSH key in the composer.json.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `composer.json`, but usually you can use the public key of the user running the process/service.  For example, if you run your process using the user `daemon`, you can create a ssh key for it in `/home/daemon` and the ssh libraries will load the public key from there as default.  (I've used that sucessfully with jenkins without having to configure anything special on it, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I have some problem with bitbucket private repos...
So I've added something like this in my project root's composer.json.

```
"require"     : {
            "php"                                      : ">=5.4.0",
            ...,
            "author/my-package"                     : "0.2"
},

"repositories": [
            {
                "type"   : "package",
                "package": {
                    "name"   : "author/my-package",
                    "version": "0.2",
                    "source" : {
                        "url"      : "ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/author/my-package",
                        "type"     : "hg",
                        "reference": "0.2"
                    },
                    "require": {
                        "php": ">=5.4.0",
                        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*"
                    },
                    "autoload": {
                        "psr-0": {
                            "PackageNameSpace": "src/"
                        },
                        "classmap": [
                            "./Module.php"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
    ...
    ]
```

So after composer.phar update it creates repo dir in vendor... But after new commit in private repo and composer.phar update it doesn't pull last changeset... It stays on head that was on first repo import